# convert list with same values to dict - smart zip (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the list:

`['apples', 400, 'sweets', 300, 'apples', 750]`

After applying function:

```
def Convert(a):
    it = iter(a)
    res_dct = dict(zip(it, it))
    return res_dct
```

I get the result:
`{'apples': 750, 'sweets': 300}`

But I need:
`{'apples': 1150, 'sweets': 300}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also try to use the **collections** *defaultdict* and *Counter* to achieve the same results.  This is just to follow your original code and flow:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

# data = ['apples', 400, 'sweets', 300, 'apples', 750]


def convert(A):
    result = defaultdict(Counter)
    it = iter(A)
    
    for fruit, count in zip(it, it):
        if fruit not in result:
            result[fruit]  = count
        else:
            result[fruit] += count
    
    return result
```

Running it:

```
print(convert(data))

# defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, {'apples': 1150, 'sweets': 300})
```